# Number of records processed in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

We're using logstash to sync Elastic search and we've around 3 million documents. It takes 3 to 4 hours to sync. Currently all we get is, it is started and stopped. Is there any way to see how many records processed in logstash ?

Comment: Which version of Logstash do you have?

Comment: We use logstash 5.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Logstash 5 and higher, the [Logstash Monitoring API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring.html) can help you. You can see and monitor what's happening inside Logstash as it processes events. If you hit the [Pipeline stats API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/node-stats-api.html#pipeline-stats) you'll get the total number of processed events per stage and plugin (input/filter/output):

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9600/_node/stats/pipelines?pretty'
```

You'll get this type of response in which you can clearly see at any time how many events have been processed:

```
{
  "pipelines" : {
    "test" : {
      "events" : {
        "duration_in_millis" : 365495,
        "in" : 216485,
        "filtered" : 216485,
        "out" : 216485,
        "queue_push_duration_in_millis" : 342466
      },
      "plugins" : {
        "inputs" : [ {
          "id" : "35131f351e2dc5ed13ee04265a8a5a1f95292165-1",
          "events" : {
            "out" : 216485,
            "queue_push_duration_in_millis" : 342466
          },
          "name" : "beats"
        } ],
        "filters" : [ {
          "id" : "35131f351e2dc5ed13ee04265a8a5a1f95292165-2",
          "events" : {
            "duration_in_millis" : 55969,
            "in" : 216485,
            "out" : 216485
          },
          "failures" : 216485,
          "patterns_per_field" : {
            "message" : 1
          },
          "name" : "grok"
        }, {
          "id" : "35131f351e2dc5ed13ee04265a8a5a1f95292165-3",
          "events" : {
            "duration_in_millis" : 3326,
            "in" : 216485,
            "out" : 216485
          },
          "name" : "geoip"
        } ],
        "outputs" : [ {
          "id" : "35131f351e2dc5ed13ee04265a8a5a1f95292165-4",
          "events" : {
            "duration_in_millis" : 278557,
            "in" : 216485,
            "out" : 216485
          },
          "name" : "elasticsearch"
        } ]
      },
      "reloads" : {
        "last_error" : null,
        "successes" : 0,
        "last_success_timestamp" : null,
        "last_failure_timestamp" : null,
        "failures" : 0
      },
      "queue" : {
        "type" : "memory"
      }
    }
   }
```

Comment: So from this stats api im not able to understand the total time taken to process all the events its received! Which field should we consider here?

Comment: @sandeepP you can check `pipelines.xyz.events.duration_in_millis`

Comment: "host" : "Shipper-Dev3",
  "version" : "5.6.1",
  "http_address" : "127.0.0.1:9600",
  "id" : "fa780ea0-502f-4995-bcc2-d61f1ba53959",
  "name" : "Shipper-Dev3",
  "pipeline" : {
    "events" : {
      "duration_in_millis" : 5235387,
      "in" : 9000000,
      "out" : 9000000,
      "filtered" : 9000000,
      "queue_push_duration_in_millis" : 1138691
    },
The unit is in milliseconds right? This is not the correct value!!!

Comment: @sandeepP Please create a new question by describing your issue and what you expect instead

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63052246/how-to-calculated-logstash-events-per-second-accurately I have added my question can you please take a look at it?